# error when parsing JSON

Tags: android, json

I just learned [Android JSON Parsing Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)

I downloaded the source code and successfully running it with default JSON data from [here](http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/)

and then I tried to copy his [JSON data](http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/) to localhost and my site

I changed this code

```
> private static String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/";
```

to

```
> private static String url = "http://yumugee.com/data.json";
```

and I got an error from log cat

```
> 02-04 19:38:48.343: E/JSON Parser(1233): Error parsing data
> org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String
> cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

I changed it again to

```
> private static String url = "http://192.168.1.100/data.json/";
```

and I got an error too

```
> 02-04 19:30:10.332: E/JSON Parser(1201): Error parsing data
> org.json.JSONException: Value <?xml of type java.lang.String cannot be
> converted to JSONObject
```

does anybody know how to solve this problem?

sry for my bad english, hope you understand what I ask. thx

```
{
"contacts": [
    {
            "id": "c200",
            "name": "Ravi Tamada",
            "email": "ravi@gmail.com",
            "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
            "gender" : "male",
            "phone": {
                "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                "home": "00 000000",
                "office": "00 000000"
            }
    },
    {
            "id": "c201",
            "name": "Johnny Depp",
            "email": "johnny_depp@gmail.com",
            "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
            "gender" : "male",
            "phone": {
                "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                "home": "00 000000",
                "office": "00 000000"
            }
    },
    {
            "id": "c202",
            "name": "Leonardo Dicaprio",
            "email": "leonardo_dicaprio@gmail.com",
            "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
            "gender" : "male",
            "phone": {
                "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                "home": "00 000000",
                "office": "00 000000"
            }
    },
    {
            "id": "c203",
            "name": "John Wayne",
            "email": "john_wayne@gmail.com",
            "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
            "gender" : "male",
            "phone": {
                "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                "home": "00 000000",
                "office": "00 000000"
            }
    },
    {
            "id": "c204",
            "name": "Angelina Jolie",
            "email": "angelina_jolie@gmail.com",
            "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
            "gender" : "female",
            "phone": {
                "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                "home": "00 000000",
                "office": "00 000000"
            }
    },
    {
            "id": "c205",
            "name": "Dido",
            "email": "dido@gmail.com",
            "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
            "gender" : "female",
            "phone": {
                "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                "home": "00 000000",
                "office": "00 000000"
            }
    },
    {
            "id": "c206",
            "name": "Adele",
            "email": "adele@gmail.com",
            "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
            "gender" : "female",
            "phone": {
                "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                "home": "00 000000",
                "office": "00 000000"
            }
    },
    {
            "id": "c207",
            "name": "Hugh Jackman",
            "email": "hugh_jackman@gmail.com",
            "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
            "gender" : "male",
            "phone": {
                "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                "home": "00 000000",
                "office": "00 000000"
            }
    },
    {
            "id": "c208",
            "name": "Will Smith",
            "email": "will_smith@gmail.com",
            "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
            "gender" : "male",
            "phone": {
                "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                "home": "00 000000",
                "office": "00 000000"
            }
    },
    {
            "id": "c209",
            "name": "Clint Eastwood",
            "email": "clint_eastwood@gmail.com",
            "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
            "gender" : "male",
            "phone": {
                "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                "home": "00 000000",
                "office": "00 000000"
            }
    },
    {
            "id": "c2010",
            "name": "Barack Obama",
            "email": "barack_obama@gmail.com",
            "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
            "gender" : "male",
            "phone": {
                "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                "home": "00 000000",
                "office": "00 000000"
            }
    },
    {
            "id": "c2011",
            "name": "Kate Winslet",
            "email": "kate_winslet@gmail.com",
            "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
            "gender" : "female",
            "phone": {
                "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                "home": "00 000000",
                "office": "00 000000"
            }
    },
    {
            "id": "c2012",
            "name": "Eminem",
            "email": "eminem@gmail.com",
            "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
            "gender" : "male",
            "phone": {
                "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                "home": "00 000000",
                "office": "00 000000"
            }
    }
]
```

}

Comment: It seems you are not getting any response. access url from browser and see you are getting any response or not.

Comment: see my answer below its work fine in java no prblm....

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run that code from localhost you should write the localhost address as following http://`10.0.2.2`/android_api/data.php, where the android_api is the folder which is inside of your wamp's www folder. Instead of yoursite.in write 10.0.2.2 or IP address of your machine. Try this.

Answer (score -1):

This error message seems like the result data is not json format . it is just xml string.

Can u show your result data here ?

Comment: the program success to running with default source http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/

but, when I tried with my file 
(copied from http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/)
I got an error

Comment: sorry , i cannt access that address before.